# Advanced Pandas column creation

Tags: python, excel, pandas, conditional-statements

I want to create a new column based on a more advanced formula that I have written on Excel. The formula on Excel is provided below and I want in the dataframe I have created to apply the same formula. I am having a bit of difficulty though implementing it in Python. Do I need to create a for loop or is there a smarter way to do it? Also, I have no idea how to compare values within the same column. For example, let's say I have a column with 10 values. How do I compare the first and the second value together?

**Excel formula wanted to be converted to python code:**

=IF(AND(A2=A3,F2=J2),O3+IF(L2>L3,(L2-L3),0),L2)

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: For the second question, you can look at the docs of the `pandas` function `shift()`. For the first one, it can be done without loops, but we can help you only if you post existing code and data samples.

Comment: I will try to figure it out myself don't worry about that. Can you please give me an example. Let's say I have a column with prices and I want to compare if the first value is equal to the second. How would you do it ina dataframe?

Comment: I uploaded a simpler formula now, assume please that A2 and A3 are part of column A etc.

Comment: You could create a pandas.Series e.g. from a list in which you calculate the required values from the respective entries in your DataFrame and then add this series as a new column to the DataFrame.

Comment: Can someone give me the code for the following thing? I cannot find it anywhere. I have a column in a dataframe with 10 values How do I compare the first and second value to see if they are the same. Let's say they are the same I want to create a new column that gives 1 otherwise 0.

Comment: It would be best if you gave a concrete example of what you have and what you want, but maybe this comes close to what you are aiming for and gives you some inspiration:      
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,3], 'B':[2,3,4,5]})    //
c = [int(df['A'][i]==df['A'][i+1]) for i in range(3)] + [0]    //
df['C'] = c